# Is $(X^T)*X$ greater than zero if $X$ doesn't equal to zero?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on below statement:
A is an $m \times n$ matrix, and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $(A^T)A$ which eigenvector $X$ doesn't equal to zero. Show that $\lambda$ is greater than or equal to zero.
I started from computing $||AX||^2$, then ended up with $\lambda\cdot (X^T)\cdot X$ is greater than or equal to zero. Then how can I know $(X^T)\cdot X$ is greater than zero?

Answer (score 7):

$X^T\cdot X$ is a sum of squares.

Comment: Totally. I forgot X is an eigenvalue. I was thinking X could be a matrix. Thank you.

Comment: @Shannon: $X$ is an eigen_vector_. An eigen_value_ is a scalar.

Comment: @Henning: Thanks; you beat me to it.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, it's an eigenvector, but the result of (X^T)X is still a sum of squares.